# /sbin/init does not exist

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

[image: /sbin/init does not exist]

After installing Arch Linux I rebooted but now I am unable to complete the boot process. I end up at the screen above with this message

`ERROR: Boot device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.`

`sh: can't access tty; job control turned off.`

and a 
`[rootfs ]#`
prompt.

I have checked and confirmed via a live disk that *sbin* exists as a **symbolic** **link** to */usr/bin*. However I do not have the *init* file/folder in my */usr/bin* directory. Where should I get the *init* file/folder? Did I miss a step during the installation? Is there anything I can do to correct this? Thanks.

Comment: On my archlinux system, `/usr/bin/init` is a symlink to `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd`, which is part of the `systemd` package. `/usr/bin/init` is itself part of the `systemd-sysvcompat` package (`systemd` is a dependency of this) and is part of the `base` group, which should have been installed as part of the [install process](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Install_the_base_packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comment, what I'd recommend you do to correct it is to reboot your system with the livecd (or whatever method you used to boot into the install environment) and redo these steps of the install process:

- [Mount the file systems](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Mount_the_file_systems)
- [Install the base packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Install_the_base_packages)
- [Reboot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide#Reboot)

If it still isn't working after this, I'd suggest checking what filesystem is actually being mounted by the bootloader. Perhaps giving a list of what files *are* present in the `/usr/bin` directory would allow us to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent half a day with this problem and eventually realized that the cause in my case was that I had set up /usr on a separate partition, and only the root partition was mounted at the point where the grub boot attempts to access /usr/bin/init.

I have solved the issue by moving the /usr file hierarchy onto the root partition.

richard

Comment: I installed Arch Linux a couple of times and never had serious issues. But today I thought to do proper partitioning, and did exactly as you did: having a separate `/usr` partition. Now I'm facing the same issue (same error message). Is there another workaround than just having `/usr` on the same partition as `/`?

Answer (score 0):

With a separate `/usr`-partition you must use a initramfs/ mkinitcpio and must add the usr-hook. There is a comment in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` that explains exactly this. Additional hooks might be necessary, too, outlined in the comments of the file. Re-generate initramfs afterwards, e.g. `mkinitcpio -P`.

Background:
Currently all major distributions are more or less broken with a separate `/usr`-partition due to inconsistent storage of binaries and libraries. According to Linux Standard Base they should use /bin, /sbin and/ or /lib. Instead most roll their own and fill /usr/bin, to trickery with /usr/sbin and mix this with different library paths. This is partly to keep users from breaking things and make it convenient and partly because there is no board above all making standards.

At least Arch Linux and Gentoo Linux offer recent guides in their Wikis for sophisticated setups. I recommend reading Gentoo's [Early Userspace Mount](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Early_Userspace_Mounting) to get an idea what it requires to create a custom initramfs. Arch Linux is a bit more high level about that.

I absolutely recommend to either stay on the safe side for common desktop systems and run with very little partitioning. Logging in daily you'll recognize quite fast that the file system fills up. It is safe to split `/home` to a separate partition (and disk) and hold all other directories on a single partition/ operating system drive.

Non-desktops/ servers should definitely split partitions to avoid filling partitions blocking the entire system. They run unattended for months or years. They write logs, data and maybe update packages automagically. You can't log in anymore to a machine that has no space left in `/tmp`, `/run` or `/var` (depending on the distribution) because of collected logs or downloaded package archives. It is also very likely then to have RAID-devices and/ or sophisticated filesystems for some partitions. Which requires even more hooks and manual configuration of boot loader and everything below `/sbin/init`.